# Read-Only files causing problems on SBS Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, read-only

I've manually migrated (Copy & Paste) a fairly large folder (~100GB) from an old Small Business Server 2003, to a new folder on SBS 2008 server.

The folder is a 'shared' area, with full access for 'Everyone' and contains various folders inside with word, excel docs inside.

The users are having problems with the majority of these files being marked as 'Read Only'

Is there a way to do a bulk removal of read only status?

I've tried to do this from folder level and come up against UAC and security denial messages.

It's driving me insane, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are they read-only from a security perspective, or do they have the read-only attribute set?

If B, tried:

Start, CMD, Ctrl+Shift+Enter (to elevate a CMD prompt)

```
CD \yoursharedfolder\

ATTRIB -R *.* /S
```

If it's permissions, you'll probably want to elevate and grant permission to everyone from ICACLS or XACLS or similar.